# Python requests login Glassdoor

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, request

I'm trying to use Python 2.7 and Requests 2.7.0 to login Glassdoor and get html response. However, we I was running following code, it always return 403 forbidden response. How can I login correctly?

```
s = requests.session()
login_data = {'username': 'myemailaddress', 'password': 'mypassword'}
s.post('https://www.glassdoor.com/profile/login_input.htm', data=login_data)
r = s.get('http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/us-reviews-SRCH_IL.0,2_IN1.htm')
print r
```

Thanks!

Comment: check in the login page if the POST is executed by a javascript/ajax call and then in what format the data is sent over (json?). Nowadays, it's quite common for pages to include javascript code that performs ajax calls to the back-end. One example are login pages, where the code encrypts/manipulates the credentials before sending them over. The back-end can discriminate if the POST request is coming from an ajax call by inspecting the header named HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH, which is set by the majority of javascript frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a slightly different approach and use a framework like Scrapy: http://scrapy.org/

That way you can manipulate the DOM directly and invoke the click events that will trigger the (most likely) javascript that will trigger the login process appropriately on the site.